# Rotate image over X, Y and Z axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to rotate an image over 3 axis in matlab.
I used the function rotx, roty, rotz to create the rotation matrix but I don't know how to use. 
Are these methods considering the center point as origin?

Comment: I read the documentation, obliviously. I don't know how to apply in image processing! An image isn't a 3 by N vector.

Comment: `rotx`, `roty` and `rotz` are part of the Mapping Toolbox.... so don't rely on those to get you your answer.  However, when you "rotate the image", it's a 2D projection so one of the 3D axes has to be set to zero... so in this case, would the image be on the `z = 0` plane?  This matters before I write an answer.

Comment: @rayryeng I think you could assume as much and give such an answer - it wouldn't be far off in any case.

Comment: @anon0909 - Certainly.  This is an interesting question, and I'm tempted to answer it, but seeing how there are already 4 close votes, it's a bit discouraging.

Comment: @rayryeng I guess I can't see those yet :)

Comment: @anon0909 - Oh :) Sorry lol.  Actually... let me write an answer.   It's not gonna look like much since the image will be on the `z = 0` plane, but what the heck right?

Comment: @anon0909 - Have a gander at my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because an image is a 2D projection from a 3D world, one of the 3D planes needs to be set to 0 if you want this to work.  I'm going to assume that the `z`-plane is equal to 0, and so the image is laying flat on the `z = 0` plane.

Basically... something like this, using the `cameraman.tif` image.  This is what it originally looks like:

[image]

Here's what it looks like in 3D.  First, load in the image, the generate `(x,y)` pairs for each intensity in the image.  This is done with `meshgrid`. Once you do this, use `scatter` to plot each point assuming `z = 0` and make the colour of each point the actual intensity seen at the image coordinate.  However, you will only see this in a 2D perspective as `scatter` is naturally 2D.  To make this 3D, change the camera view so that you're looking at the image with MATLAB's default 3D view, then add some things like the labels and a grid as well as reversing the `y` coordinate as the `y` coordinates for images are positive going downwards:

```
%// Load in the image
im = imread('cameraman.tif');

%// Generate coordinates and unravel into a single vector
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(im,2), 1:size(im,1));
x_coord = X(:); y_coord = Y(:);

%// Plot the image as a scatter plot
scatter(x_coord, y_coord, 2, repmat(double(im(:)), 1, 3)/255);
view(3); grid; xlabel('Columns'); ylabel('Rows');
axis ij
```

We get this:

[image]

However, this is only for grayscale images.  If you want to do the same in colour, you need to change the way you're specifying the colour of each point.  That's simply done by extracting out the red, green and blue planes and putting them as a single column in the colour matrix as the fourth argument.  Specifically, the `scatter` command is now:

```
red = reshape(im(:,:,1), [], 1);
green = reshape(im(:,:,2), [], 1);
blue = reshape(im(:,:,3), [], 1);
scatter(x_coord, y_coord, 2, double([red green blue])/255);
```

So now we have this, what you simply need to do is take the `X` and `Y` coordinates that were generated in the previous step and rotate each of them with a rotation matrix.  Bear in mind that the `Z` coordinate is all zeroes.

There is a rotation matrix defined with respect to each axis you want to rotate the points with.  The rotation matrix for each axis is seen below:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)</sup>

As such, it's simply a matter of taking the unraveled coordinates above, applying them to a rotation matrix then using these new coordinates and plotting the points.  Bear in mind that for image coordinates, the `y` axis is positive going downwards, so rotating in a clockwise direction is for positive angles and rotating counter-clockwise is for negative angles.

To rotate a 3D point assuming that the origin is at `(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)` (which is our case as well), it is simply a matrix multiplication:

```
Pout = R*P;
```

`P` is a 3 x 1 vector of the `(x,y,z)` points and `Pout` is the output vector (also 3 x 1) that is rotated.  Therefore, if you want to do this for all of our points, you'd have to make `P` into a `3 x N` matrix where `N` is the total number of pixels in the image, apply `R*P`, then use the resulting points as input into `scatter`.

We can show what happens when we rotate with each axis independently.

## `x`-axis

First create a rotation matrix for the `x` axis for a given rotation angle `theta`:

```
theta = pi/3; %// 60 degree rotation for example
Rx = [1 0 0; 0 cos(theta) -sin(theta); 0 sin(theta) cos(theta)];
```

Now that you're done, rotate the points:

```
Pout = Rx*[x_coord.'; y_coord.'; zeros(1,numel(x_coord))];
```

Once you're done, call `scatter` with these new points.  What I'll do instead is call `scatter3` as this is designed for 3D points and I'll also need to rotate the camera to see things properly:

```
scatter3(Pout(1,:), Pout(2,:), Pout(3,:), 2, repmat(double(im(:)), 1, 3)/255);
axis ij; xlabel('Columns'); ylabel('Rows');
view(-105, 35);
```

If you have colour images, make sure you change the fourth argument to what I talked about at the beginning of this post.

We get this:

[image]

The `x` axis here is the columns, and rotating is similar to imagining a book laying flat on the `z = 0` plane and opening up a page from the book.  The spine of the book would be the `x` axis, or the columns.

## `y`-axis

You do the same thing but with a different rotation matrix.  However, to give you a better perspective of rotating this way, I'll need to change the camera angle slightly:

```
theta = pi/3; %// 60 degree rotation for example
Ry = [cos(theta) 0 sin(theta); 0 1 0; -sin(theta) 0 cos(theta)];
Pout = Ry*[x_coord.'; y_coord.'; zeros(1,numel(x_coord))];
scatter3(Pout(1,:), Pout(2,:), Pout(3,:), 2, repmat(double(im(:)), 1, 3)/255);
axis ij; xlabel('Columns'); ylabel('Rows');
view(5,30); %// Change camera angle so that you're looking at the x plane better
```

This is what we get:

[image]

Same effect, but the axis of rotation has changed.  The spine of the book is now the with respect to the rows, not the columns.

## `z`-axis

This one is pretty benign.  This should have the effect of rotating a piece of paper on a table with no elevation:

```
theta = pi/3; %// 60 degree rotation for example
Rz = [cos(theta) -sin(theta) 0; sin(theta) cos(theta) 0; 0 0 1];
Pout = Rz*[x_coord.'; y_coord.'; zeros(1,numel(x_coord))];
scatter3(Pout(1,:), Pout(2,:), Pout(3,:), 2, repmat(double(im(:)), 1, 3)/255);
axis ij; xlabel('Columns'); ylabel('Rows');
```

.... and:

[image]

---

Hopefully this will be more than enough to get you started.  Good luck!

Comment: That's a [very nice answer](https://goo.gl/gaxlaH)

Comment: @StewieGriffin - Haha thanks :)

Comment: I did,  it works.  You Just forgot talk About the translation i had to do, but it was the easiest part. As i want a final image in the end i had to use the Pout as Index from original image to rebuild the new one. If the Index is out of bounds i add zero.

Comment: @DavidClifte That wasn't very clear in your post.  You only wanted to know about how to rotate images and I showed you that quite well, but not talk about how to actually create the image in the end.  That being said, I'm glad you figured that out!