# Simulate 3D rotation

Tags: matlab, 3d, rotation

Having an image, I want to rotate it in a 3D way,I used the 3D rotation matrix definition:  `R= Rx*Ry*Rz` with: `Rx (Ry,Rz)` is the rotation matrix with angle around `x (y,z)` axis. So as input, I just give the 3 angles, and as output I get the deformed image. the MATLAB code is:

```
Rx = [1 0 0; 0 cos(theta) -sin(theta); 0 sin(theta) cos(theta)];
Ry = [cos(beta) 0 sin(beta); 0 1 0; -sin(beta) 0 cos(beta)];
Rz = [ cos(phi) -sin(phi) 0; sin(phi) cos(phi) 0; 0 0 1];
R = Rx * Ry * Rz;
T = projective2d( R );
I_deformed = imwarp(I,T);
```

somehow the angles around  x axis and y axis are not giving me the predicted results, I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what it is, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve the problem without the Image Processing Toolbox. A lot of information regarding the rotation in 3D-space could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299887/rotate-image-over-x-y-and-z-axis-in-matlab).

I used some stuff from this page to rotate the image. Then I just set the view property of the plot, in order to simulate the projection onto XY-plane.

Here are the original and the rotated images:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
path = 'https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg';
[I, map]=imread(path,'jpg');

x_size = size(I, 2);
y_size = size(I, 1);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:x_size, 1:y_size);
x_coord = X(:);y_coord = Y(:);

red = reshape(I(:,:,1), [], 1);
green = reshape(I(:,:,2), [], 1);
blue = reshape(I(:,:,3), [], 1);

%Set the rotation angles
theta = pi/3; beta = pi/4; phi = pi/6;

%Define the rotation matrices
Rx = [1 0 0; 0 cos(theta) -sin(theta); 0 sin(theta) cos(theta)];
Ry = [cos(beta) 0 sin(beta); 0 1 0; -sin(beta) 0 cos(beta)];
Rz = [ cos(phi) -sin(phi) 0; sin(phi) cos(phi) 0; 0 0 1];
R = Rx * Ry * Rz;

%Apply the rotation
Pout = R*[x_coord.'; y_coord.'; zeros(1,numel(x_coord))];
scatter3(Pout(1,:), Pout(2,:), Pout(3,:), 2, double([red green blue])/255);

%change the direction of the Y-axis
axis ij; 
%set the axes to the same scale
axis equal; 

%Add axes-labels if needed
%xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y'); zlabel('Z');

%Simulate the 2D-Projection on the XY-plane by setting the view
view(0,90);

%Turn off the grid and the background
grid off;
set(gca,'visible','off');
```

Comment: Thank you, you are life-saver, it is working perfectly... but still can't understand why The 3D rotation matrix is not working with the  Image Processing Toolbox...