# Rotate image around world x axis

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation, computer-vision

Having this coordinate system:

[image]

And this dominant vertical vanishing point:
[image]

I would like to rotate the image around x axis so the vanishing point is at infinity. That means that all vertical lines are parallel.

I am using matlab. I find the line segmentes using LSD and the vanishing point using homogeneous coordinates. I would like to use angle-axis representation, then convert it to a rotation matrix and pass this to imwarp and get the rotated image. Also would be good to know how to rotate the segments. The segments are as (x1,y1,x2,y2).

Image above example:

Vanishin point in homogenous coordinates:

```
(x,y,z) = 1.0e+05 * [0.4992   -2.2012    0.0026]
```

Vanishin point in cartesian coordinates (what you see in the image):

```
(x,y) = [190.1335 -838.3577]
```

Question: With this vanishing point how do I compute the rotation matrix in the world x axis as explained above?

Comment: you want an affine transform/homography

Comment: You mean something like `rotMat = vrrotvec2mat([u, theta])` ?

Comment: That doesn't work Jon. I just don't know how to do it @Jon

Comment: 3D rotations have a lot of ambiguities, and convention-dependent parts, so it's hard to just plug-and-play. If you can add more to your question, like a small example of actual code and example numbers, I might be able to help.

Comment: Updated question @Jon Would be great if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is rotating the image so that the vector from the origin to the vanishing point, is instead pointing directly vertical, here's an example.

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure;imagesc(I);set(gcf,'colormap',gray);

vp=-[190.1335 -838.3577,0]; %3d version,just for cross-product use,-ve ?
y=[0,1,0]; %The vertical axis on the plot
u = cross(vp,y); %you know it's going to be the z-axis
theta = -acos(dot(vp/norm(vp),y)); %-ve ?
rotMat = vrrotvec2mat([u, theta]);
J=imwarp(I,affine2d (rotMat));
figure;imagesc(J);set(gcf,'colormap',gray); %tilted image
```

You can play with the negatives, and plotting, since I'm not sure about those parts applying to your situation. The negatives may come from plotting upside down, or from rotation of the world vs. camera coordinate system, but I don't have time to think about it right now.

**EDIT**

If you want to rotation about the X-axis, this might work (adapted from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/113074-how-to-rotate-an-image-along-y-axis), or check out: [Rotate image over X, Y and Z axis in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299887/rotate-image-over-x-y-and-z-axis-in-matlab)

```
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(I);
newRows = rows * cos(theta);
rotatedImage = imresize(I, [newRows, columns]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon. I already tried this but then the affine2d gives problems: "The final column of an affine transformation matrix must consist of zeroes, except for a one in the last row". And the rotation matrix is:
   [-0.9752,    0.2212,   -0.0104;
   -0.2212,   -0.9752,   -0.0012;
   -0.0104,    0.0012,    0.9999]

Comment: How do you get the matrix? That error means you're not rotating about the z-axis, and `affine2d` can only be 2D (aka, around the z axis only). The rotation matrix you have is a 3D rotation about all axes, so I suppose you have to look at `affine3d`, or use the  link I pointed to at the bottom.