# How to rotate an image around the x or y axis (in 3D space)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to rotate an image (a 100 x 100 uint8 matrix) around the x or y axis, in 3D space.

This is an online GUI I found to illustrate what I want: https://www.3dtransformer.com/
But I would like to automate this in Matlab, so I can better control the size.

I have tried using imrotate, rotate, as well as this code below, taken from https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html:

```
udata = [0 1];   vdata = [0 1]; 
tform = maketform("projective",[ 0 0;  1  0;  1  1; 0 1],...
                               [-4 2; -8 -3; -3 -5; 6 3]); [B,xdata,ydata] = 
imtransform(img_orig,tform,"bicubic", ...
                              "udata",udata,...
                              "vdata",vdata,...
                              "size",size(img_orig),...
                              "fill",128); 
subplot(1,2,1); 
imshow(img_orig,"XData",udata,"YData",vdata) 
subplot(1,2,2); 
imshow(B,"XData",xdata,"YData",ydata);
```

I don't understand how to rotate the image a certain number of degrees (let's say 60 degrees) **towards or away** from me, on the **x or y axis**. Also, this method does not seem to retain size.

Please advise, thank you so much!

Comment: That is not a rotation, it is a perspective transformation. You are deforming the image to make it look like the surface it is displayed on is tilted. But ultimately you are transforming a 2D image into another 2D image, so you really can’t apply an actual rotation operation.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299887/rotate-image-over-x-y-and-z-axis-in-matlab/32302400#32302400) should be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes exactly this, thank you both for putting my thoughts into words, and for the resource!

Comment: I've been playing around with the code. [beaker's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299887/rotate-image-over-x-y-and-z-axis-in-matlab/32302400#32302400) is almost what I am looking for, but as @Cris Luengo pointed out, I need to **deform** the image to make it look like the surface is tilted. Which function would achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Note: It would be nice to use projtform2d ([link]:(https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/creating-a-gallery-of-transformed-images.html)), but I have Matlab 2021a.